# Words inside square brackes - RegExp

Tags: java, regex, gwt

```
String linkPattern = "\\[[A-Za-z_0-9]+\\]";  
String text = "[build]/directory/[something]/[build]/";   
RegExp reg = RegExp.compile(linkPattern,"g");  
MatchResult matchResult = reg.exec(text);  
for (int i = 0; i < matchResult.getGroupCount(); i++) {  
    System.out.println("group" + i + "=" + matchResult.getGroup(i));  
}
```

I am trying to get all blocks  which are encapsulated by squared bracets form a path string:
and I only get group0="[build]" what i want is: 
1:"[build]" 2:"[something]" 3:"[build]"

EDIT:
just to be clear words inside the brackets are generated with random text

```
public static String genText()
{
    final int LENGTH = (int)(Math.random()*12)+4;

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int x = 0; x < LENGTH; x++)
    {
        sb.append((char)((int)(Math.random() * 26) + 97));
    }
    String str = sb.toString();
    str = str.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1);
    return str;
}
```

EDIT 2:
JDK works fine, GWT RegExp gives this problem

SOLVED:
Answer from Didier L

```
String linkPattern = "\\[[A-Za-z_0-9]+\\]";
    String result = "";
String text = "[build]/directory/[something]/[build]/";
RegExp reg = RegExp.compile(linkPattern,"g");
MatchResult matchResult = null;
while((matchResult=reg.exec(text)) != null){
    if(matchResult.getGroupCount()==1) 
        System.out.println( matchResult.getGroup(0));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which regex library you are using but using the one from the JDK it would go along the lines of

```
String linkPattern = "\\[[A-Za-z_0-9]+\\]";
String text = "[build]/directory/[something]/[build]/";
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(linkPattern);
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(text);
while (mat.find()) {
    System.out.println(mat.group());
}
```

Output:

```
[build]
[something]
[build]
```

Comment: JDK works fine... already checked, the problem i am having is the RegExp from GWT

Comment: Ok, I have never used it but looking at the API, shouldn't you call `exec` withing a loop until it returns `null`? As it is a global `RegExp` it will use the last index to know from where to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was my wrong use of RegExp... Ill edit the main quiestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
String linkPattern = "(\\[[A-Za-z_0-9]+\\])*";
```

EDIT:

Second try:

```
String linkPattern = "\\[(\\w+)\\]+"
```

Third try, see http://rubular.com/r/eyAQ3Vg68N

Comment: Anser: group0=[build]
group1=[build] .. still [something] is missing

Comment: I suspect that the "something" you are talking about isn't really "something" in your real program, but some text that you changed to "something" in order not to post it here. Make sure the real text matches your regex for the block content, meaning that it's matchable by ``[A-Za-z_0-9]+``.

Comment: there is no real text, i am testing it with dummy words now, and most of the dummy are generated random... i do not think that [dfakjth] is readable so i changed it in [something].. but in production i will need [fraction] for example. I edited the post so you can check

Comment: For the secondy Try: group0=[build]
group1=build

Comment: Rublar works fine, I think RegExp has some problems... maybe I am not using something right.. ill recheck again, but thanks alot

Comment: Ok, but strangely enough I got some similar sorts of problems while tinkering with rubular. Try your original regex there, you get pretty much the same error.